# How to do sqlsrv_query in model ? How to call the database connection inside model?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

Hi I using Codeigniter with MSSQL i have connected the database and its working and i need to use the connection string in model controller. Here is the below code that i given in database .php file

for testing purpose i given a query in this file itself and it is working

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "Admin\SQLEXPRESS"; // or put the IP of your SQL Server Instance
$db['default']['port'] = 1433; // or the port you configured on step 6
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; // Pay attention to this, codeigniter makes true for default
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$serverName = $db['default']['hostname']; //serverName\instanceName

 // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
 // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
 $connectionInfo = array( 'Database' => $db['default']['database']);
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

 if ($conn)
 {
      $sql="SELECT * from dbo.LAYER";
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
      {
      $result_array[] = $row;
      }
      print("<pre>");
      print_r($result_array);
      exit;   


 }
 else 
{
  echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
  die ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
```

and in model I tried this but its not working

```
class welcome_m extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('default',true);           
    }
    function welcome_check()
    {
      $sql="SELECT * from dbo.LAYER";
      $stmt = $this->db->sqlsrv_query($sql);
     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
      {
      $result_array[] = $row;
      }
      print("<pre>");
      print_r($result_array);
      exit;
   }
```

This is the model file. How to call the database connection inside model
Thank you

Comment: Add it into the `welcome_check($conn)`.

Comment: how i can add this function is calling from controller know

Comment: I'm just throwing out ideas, to be honest, I don't really know. Why can't you just create the connection inside that class since you are extending it anyway? If you have it working out in your other portion why can't you just throw that code into the `welcome_check`?

Comment: Because i am using codeigniter

Comment: I can do the connection inside welcome_check function but for all the function i have to do the same connection again and again thats the problem

Comment: So create the connection one time in a new method inside that `welcome_m` class called `protected function msdb()` or something and use that in your other functions. Then it's only set once but available everywhere. Again, just throwing ideas out there! :)

Comment: thats y i craeted a connection in the database.php file and i called that file inside model so that i can use the same connection through out the model

Comment: but i dont know how to call that function using oop

Comment: Please help me in this

Comment: Is this the part you added? `$this->load->database('default',true);`

Comment: yes $this->load->database('default',true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at the `Codeigniter` documentation it says this when loading a database it would be something like...but don't downvote me for trying!:

```
protected $MyMSSQL;

function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();
        $this->MyMSSQL = $this->load->database('default',true);           
    }

function welcome_check()
    {
        $db    =    $this->MyMSSQL;
        $stmt  =    $db->query("SELECT * from dbo.LAYER");
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $result_array[] = $row;
            }

        print("<pre>");
        print_r($result_array);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::sqlsrv_query() its showing this error

Comment: Try `$db->query("SELECT * from dbo.LAYER");` instead of `$db->sqlsrv_query("SELECT * from dbo.LAYER");`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around I was able to connect SQL Server in my code(model), below is my data base file and a sample function in model:

**I am putting a sample function from my models:**

```
public function getCommandFields($name)
    {
        // Load Sql Server Connection

        $this->sqlsrvr = $this->load->database('test', true);

        $qry ="select  SPECIFIC_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, PARAMETER_NAME, DATA_TYPE, 
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,PARAMETER_MODE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Parameters
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME  ='".$name."'";


         $query = $this->sqlsrvr->query($qry);
         $fields = array();
         foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $fields[]=  $row;
        }

        return $fields;

    }
```

**DATA BASE FILE**

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = "192.168.12.123";
$db['test']['username'] = "sa";
$db['test']['password'] = "password";
$db['test']['database'] = "Hospital";
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = "sqlsrv";
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['test']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['test']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```